# MySQL: why isn't 'FOO' IS NULL optimized away?

Tags: mysql

MySQL 5.5.28. I have two tables `Person` and `Message` and the latter has a foreign key to the former. Each table has `id` as the primary key column, and the `Person` table also has a column `personId` which is (uniquely) indexed.

The query below should take advantage of the `personId` key index, but instead MySQL requires scanning the entire `Message` table for some reason:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT `m`.*
    -> FROM
    ->   `Message` AS `m`
    -> LEFT JOIN
    ->   `Person` AS `p` ON (`m`.`person` = `p`.`id`)
    -> WHERE
    ->   'M002649397' IS NULL OR
    ->   `p`.`personId` = 'M002649397';
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref            | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL           | 273220 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | pcom.m.person  |      1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------+--------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But when I comment out the `'M002649397' IS NULL OR` clause (which has no effect on the result), the query suddenly gets more efficient:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT `m`.*
    -> FROM
    ->   `Message` AS `m`
    -> LEFT JOIN
    ->   `Person` AS `p` ON (`m`.`person` = `p`.`id`)
    -> WHERE
    -> --  'M002649397' IS NULL OR
    ->   `p`.`personId` = 'M002649397';
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p     | const | PRIMARY,personId   | personId           | 767     | const |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | m     | ref   | FK9C2397E7A0F6ED11 | FK9C2397E7A0F6ED11 | 9       | const |    3 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

My question is: why isn't MySQL smart enough to realize that `'M002649397' IS NULL` is always false, optimize it away, and save having to needlessly scan every row in a huge table?

In other words, does the MySQL optimizer not know that `'M002649397' IS NULL` is always false, or is it failing to apply that optimization to the query when constructing its query plan?

Comment: Perhaps the query planner wasn't designed that way because they expected developers not to write queries that we can easily optimize manually? It does seem a little silly to even have that condition in the query. A better question might be, "Why do I want this in my query? Can I find a better way of generating the query?" If you're generating the query code side, then you should have the ability to leave out the condition.

Comment: Try [`EXPLAIN EXTENDED` followed by `SHOW WARNINGS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-extended.html).

Comment: @jpmc26: Actualy their optimizer is designed to perform such optimizations http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/where-optimizations.html

Comment: It should be optimized by constant folding, it looks like they missed this case.

Comment: @Archie: I'd try to file a bug

Comment: What happens if you change the where clause to `WHERE 0 or \`p\`.\`personId\` = 'M002649397'`

Comment: What difference does this make? It doesn't optimize it, so don't do it.

Comment: @Barmar: there is a chance a real query is being composed in application's runtime from multiple predicates, which sometimes are falsy by definition and OP caught a case when the performance degrades in one of such cases. And it doesn't make much sense to test it manually before adding to the query.

Comment: I wonder is it the same result if `IS NULL` is replaced by any other constant expression.

Comment: could it be that the optimizer blindly avoid any optimization on `IS NULL` in an outer join setup, without actually checking the other part of the predicate (ie. if it's a column or not)?

Comment: @Barmar: changing to `WHERE 0` doesn't help.

Comment: @zerkms: Bug filed: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69359

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, this query is a simplified version of a programmatically generated query, which are very common.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, what is more interesting, is that the documentation says that MySQL is smart enough to do this (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-primary-optimizations.html)).

This would seem to come under the heading "8.2.1.2. Eliminating “Dead” Code".

I suppose the reason is that the developers did not consider an expression such as " is not null" when the code was written.  The documentation gives many examples based on constant propagation (`x1 = 2 and x2 = x1` becomes `x1 = 2 and x2 = 2`).  `is null` probably does arise in this situation.

Comment: He mentioned that `0 or personid = 'xxx'` also isn't optimized, so it has nothing to do with optimizing `is not null`. It sounds like they don't optimize `0 or <expression>` into `<expression>`.

Comment: @Barmar . . . (Hi Barmar, I think we used to work together.)  This is not the first time that I've found MySQL documentation more optimistic than the MySQL implementation.

Comment: "MySQL documentation more optimistic than the MySQL implementation" --- Documentation Driven Development: you declare more features than you have and implement it as soon as people actually point to a bug

Comment: @zerkms . . . After I wrote that comment, I realized it would probably come across as too negative.  The only other case I've experienced this is with index optimization of aggregations.  `group by` just does not seem to use indexes in practice, but the do according to the documentation.  Overall, I'm impressed with the documentation . . . and this is straying from the OP.

Comment: (Yes, at TMC). Pretty depressing -- optimizing identities when simplifying expressions is a CS 101 exercise, and any decent compiler should do it.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: "it would probably come across as too negative" --- don't be too rigorous to yourself, mysql deserves it :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a [verified MySQL bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69359).

You can not have one execution plan for the condition:

WHERE (0 = 1) OR p.personId = 'string_constant';

and another execution plan for:

WHERE p.personId = 'string_constant';

because (0 = 1) always results in FALSE, which makes the above two queries 100 % identical.

You can see in the bug report itself that execution plan when (0 = 1) OR is present is much worse then the one where the expression is only the equality of a column to a constant.

*Note this is [fixed in MariaDB](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-4817).

Comment: OP already know that....Just look carefully at the bug report....it's from him :)